# How to print LISP list side by side?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

i have a two list as

```
(defvar product-list (list "apple" "banana") )
(defvar price-list (list 5 10) )
```

i want to print this as

> apple : 5
>
> banana : 10

how to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use loop, for example:

```
(defvar product-list (list "apple" "banana") )
(defvar price-list (list 5 10) )

(loop for product in product-list
      for price in price-list
      do (format t "~A : ~A~%"
                 product
                 price))
```

Comment: thnx buddy. Worked

Answer (score 4):

No `loop`:

```
(format nil "~{~{~A~T:~T~A~}~^~%~}"
        (mapcar
         (function list)
         (list "apple" "banana")
         (list 5 10)))
```

return:

```
"apple : 5
banana : 10"
```

reference:

A Few FORMAT Recipes: http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/a-few-format-recipes.html